# Poder subir un formdata con los encabezados httpHeaders

Tags: angular, django, typescript

Buenas tardes a toda la comunidad, estoy intentando subir un formdata desde angular hacia un servicio que esta en django rest framework, sin embargo es importante enviarle el httpHeaders debido a que solo debe hacerse si el usuario esta autenticado, de esta manera paso el formdata:

//Servicio cuando el usuario da click

```
crearEvento(){
if (this.idLastEvent === undefined){
   this.idLastEvent=0;
}
this.myForm.patchValue({
  id_event: this.idLastEvent+1
});
//Creacion de la constante evento
this.evento  = {
id_event: this.idLastEvent+1,
id_client: this.idClient,
event_name:this.myForm.get('event_name').value,
event_desc:this.myForm.get('event_desc').value,
event_date:this.myForm.get('event_date').value,
event_date_end:this.myForm.get('event_date_finish').value,
event_tipo:this.myForm.get('event_type').value,
event_class:this.myForm.get('event_class').value,
event_image:this.myFile,
event_zoom_id:this.myForm.get('event_zoom_id').value,
event_zoom_pwd:this.myForm.get('event_zoom_pwd').value,
event_payment:this.myForm.get('event_payment').value
};

//Arreglar el fomrulario
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('event_id', (this.evento.id_event).toString());
formData.append('event_name', this.evento.event_name);
formData.append('event_desc', this.evento.event_desc);
formData.append('event_date', this.datepipe.transform(this.evento.event_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
formData.append('event_date_finish', this.datepipe.transform(this.evento.event_date_end, 
'yyyy-MM-dd'));
formData.append('event_tipo', this.evento.event_tipo);
formData.append('event_class', this.evento.event_class);
formData.append('event_image', this.myFile);
formData.append('event_zoom_id', this.evento.event_zoom_id);
formData.append('event_zoom_pwd', this.evento.event_zoom_pwd);
formData.append('event_payment', this.evento.event_payment?"True":"False");
formData.append('event_change_file', "True");
console.log(formData.get('event_image'))
this.eventService.createEvent(formData,this.idClient).subscribe(data=>{
   console.log(data);
});
```

}

Aqui esta el eventService.createEvent:

```
createEvent(body,idClient) {
return this.http.post(this.endpoints.createEvent(idClient), body,  {headers: this.globalService.headers()});
 }
```

Y aqui esta el servicio en django:

```
class EventViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
```

¿Como podria enviar el formdata sin problema?

Muchisimas gracias de antemano

---

La idea es poder guardar el token en un localstorage (en el momento del login) y pasarlo al servicio de la siguiente forma

```
var header = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Authorization', 'Token '+  localStorage.getItem("token"))
}
return this.http.post(this.endpoints.createEvent(idClient), body,  header);
```

Muchas gracias a todos

Comment: ¿Qué cabecera en específico se tiene que enviar? ¿`this.globalService.headers()` contiene esa cabecera?

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda la idea es enviar el token este método this.globalService.headers() tiene lo siguiente :                                                                                           
 headers() {
    const token = this.getToken();
    console.log(this.httpHeaders)
    if (token !== '') {
      this.httpHeaders['Authorization'] = 'Token ' + token;}
    }
    return new HttpHeaders(this.httpHeaders);
  }

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente lo pude solucionar poniendo este codigo dentro del header

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58780482/cant-send-form-data-with-a-bearer-token-in-angular

Muchas gracias

Comment: Sería que bueno que pusieras el código también para enriquecer la respuesta y que otros usuarios puedan llegar fácilmente a ella.